# tensorflow 1.15 compatibility with tensorflow 2.3?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I setup the linux computer with tensorflow 2.3 with cuda 11.0 & cudnn 8.

I was keras and torch,

but this time I tried to use tensorflow 1.15 from the virtual environment, but whenever I typed
with Seesion:

Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.10.0'; dlerror :libcudart.so.10.0 : cannot open shared object file; dlerror : libcudart.so.10.0 cannot open shard object file: No such file or directory ; LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cud-10.1/lib64

i want to ask if there is new version of tensorflow, we cannot use older tensorflow for it?
if we can, then is it fine just download cuda 10.0 in to my desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorflow<2 is not supported by cuda>9.

You can build tensorflow from source with cuda10

Answer (score 0):

Different versions of tensorflow are built with different cuda versions.
The prebuilt Tensorflow 1.15 needs cuda 10.0.

You can either build Tensorflow from source on your machine, in which case you can build it with the version of cuda you have available, or install cuda 10.0 alongside version cuda 11

Comment: "install cuda 10.0 alongside version cuda 11" - How to do this?